# How do you fetch the N newest Models in Google App Engine with NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have potentially thousands of 'Report' Models stored. I'm trying to get the 50 newest Reports ordered by a DateTimeProperty. Although my existing query does fetch the Reports in order of new to old, it does not return the *newest* 50. Instead it returns an older (sorted) selection. What am I missing here?

```
class Report(ndb.polymodel.PolyModel):
    received_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add=True)
    report_state = ndb.StringProperty(choices=set(['unresolved', 'resolved']))

...

reports_query = Report.query(
    Report.report_state == 'resolved',
    ancestor = some_key) \
    .order(Report.received_time)
resolved_reports = reports_query.fetch(50)
```

When I'm testing, if I have 200 Reports in my datastore and I fetch 200, I am getting all Reports sorted in the right order.

Comment: I can verify that fetch is returning 50 Models, but they are not the 50 latest. However the list contents are sorted from newer to older.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query sorts in the increasing order of the `received_time`, so you are getting those with earlier times (smaller time = older time). To get the oldest ones change the order:

```
.order(-Report.received_time)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was dumb of me. My original query was returning the 50 oldest Models, but the list they were returned in was sorted from new to old. I did try the negated order, but only saw that the list was in order of old to new and looked no further.